# glTF 2.0 Validation error: ACCESSOR_VECTOR3_NON_UNIT

Tags: error, gltf

I’m getting an error from a .glb file that was exported from Blender using the Khronos glTF Validator. I’ve been searching online for the past couple of days, but can’t find any information describing what this error is all about and how I might resolve it. I’m fairly new to 3D modeling so any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Here is a snippet from the validation report:

```
{
“code”: “ACCESSOR_VECTOR3_NON_UNIT”,
“message”: “Vector3 at accessor indices 4830…4832 is not of unit length: 0.”,
“severity”: 0,
“pointer”: “/meshes/0/primitives/4/attributes/NORMAL”
}
```

What I need to know is, what is the error referring to, and how can I find the source of the problem inside Blender so that I can correct it?

Comment: [Looks like Blender produces a file that doesn't fulfill the specification](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Validator/blob/master/ISSUES.md). Please report this on Blender's bug tracker (*Help > Report a Bug* in Blender) and attach the project that produces the problematic file when exported. Try to keep the project as small as possible.

Comment: This question should not have been closed, as it has a simple answer within Blender:  In Edit Mode, select all, and go to the menus, `Mesh -> Clean Up -> Degenerate Dissolve`

Comment: Specifically, these are zero-length normal vectors, produced by degenerate geometry, which is invalid in glTF.

Comment: @emackey Thanks, I went through several of the "clean" options, Degenerate Disolve, Merge by Distance, Delete Loose, before posting this question, and none worked. I eventually discovered an export warning after launching Blender from the command line:  WARNING: Could not calculate tangents. Please try to triangulate the mesh first. I added a Triangulate modier to the mesh and that did the trick.